# After row selected I want the value of a specific cell where header = "header name" in datagridview

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

I have a datagriview when the user click on a row it turns blue. I neeed the information of a specific cell where the header name is "armario" how can i get the value so I can use it later in a new window.

Here is my code in the backend:

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Color myRgbColor = new Color();
        myRgbColor = Color.FromArgb(27,155,255);

        foreach (GridViewRow row in editingGrid.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowIndex == editingGrid.SelectedIndex)
            {
                row.BackColor = myRgbColor;
            }
            else
            {
                row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            }
        }
}
```

Here is want i want I have in the front-end:

```
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Armario" SortExpression="armario">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("armario") %>' runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCloset" Text='<%# Eval("armario") %>' runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did in the frontend, I added a ID.

```
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Armario" SortExpression="armario">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="tblCloset" Text='<%# Eval("armario") %>' runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCloset" Text='<%# Eval("armario") %>' runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

And here is want i did in the backend.

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Color myRgbColor = new Color();
    myRgbColor = Color.FromArgb(27,155,255);

    foreach (GridViewRow row in editingGrid.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowIndex == editingGrid.SelectedIndex)
        {
            row.BackColor = myRgbColor;
            closet= (editingGrid.SelectedRow.FindControl("tblCloset") as Label).Text; //This is the only line I had to changed in the backend.
        }
        else
        {
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

I found the solution here https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-get-Selected-Row-cell-value-from-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx